# bash awk seems to get numbers wrong

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file `fake_data.csv` that stores the following data:

```
ts, value
1527392000, 1
1535392000, 10
1524392000, 200
```

I ran this command and it doesn't print out anything:

```
value=$(date +%s) | awk '{ if ($1>=$value) {print}}'  ./fake_data.csv

echo $value:
1526061574
```

So I think I should get two rows because the 1527392000>$value, and 1535392000>$value.

What went wrong here? Is it because the integers overflows? Does bash support long int type?

Comment: awk is not included with bash, part of bash, etc. It's just awk, not "bash awk".

Comment: That said, why do you think awk can see your shell variable named `value`? Awk can't see shell variables any more than, say, a Python script can see variables set inside a Java program that started it.

Comment: `awk -v value="$(date +%s)" '$1 >= value { print }'`

Comment: Got you! Thank you very much!!